# How can I include a page section on multiple others?

Tags: asp.net

My title is somewhat vague, because I'm not exactly sure how to ask what I want.

I have aspx pages with master pages, but on a few, I want to include another page as a section.

I.e.,

The "template" page, lets call it `buttons.aspx` would contain facebook and twitter buttons, and on whichever pages I wanted I would do something like `<include buttons.aspx>` (pseudo). How would I do this in an aspx project? Would I have to do another master page? What if I want to include `buttons.aspx` content in a different place on each page? Is this possible?

Comment: I think ASCX user controls can be used for that, but I'm not sure. That's why I'm posting it as a comment, not an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should read about User control - aka ASCX.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As [Royi Says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8563804), User controls are the way to go.  You can even have the user controls behave differently on different pages via properties.

A second, often inferior method to accomplish this task is via

```
<!--#include file="somefile.htm"-->
```

This is a static include (does not do processing, support events, etc.) and is rarely what you want.  However, it is an appropriate choice for some forms of static content.